# Error with "npm run" "npm run submitTransaction"

Tags: hyperledger-composer

[This is the error I got while running the command "npm run" in the /Users/user_name/Desktop/fabric_composer/sample-networks/packages/DigitalProperty-Network/lib directory.

The 2nd screenshot shows the command I ran, which can be found at this in tutorial https://fabric-composer.github.io/start/getting-started-cmd-line.html[][1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVH3K.png)

The command was supposed to return "available via npm run-script: submitTransaction" but it didn't. The directions say to run the "npm run" command in the Getting Started Directory, but I can't find it.

Comment: The command was supposed to return "available via `npm run-script`:
  submitTransaction" but it didn't. The directions say to run the "npm run" command in the Getting Started Directory, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to work through the steps on the page you described, you need to have completed the getting started tutorial (the quickstart link) mentioned at the top of the page. The link to the page is
https://fabric-composer.github.io/start/quickstart.html
which describes cloning the sample applications and running the sample application.